# Views not showing Pager

Tags: views, paging

I created a Views out of some nodes and displaying it. And I've done views theming of type **Row style output** and saved the file in following format **views-view-fields--[views machine name].tpl.php**. All is working great except the views pager/navigation. It's simply not showing up, I tried all type of combinations : **full pager, mini pager, Display a specified number of items and display all items,** but of no use.

One important thing: I'm also using using **CCK pager** which might be overriding the views pager. For this issue, I tried changing **views pager id**, but that too failed.

Comment: I have the same problem, even without CCK pager. We have probably found the same suggestion about the pager id, which surprisingly worked for others, but not for me. Ironically, the pager shows up in the preview pane, doesn't it?

Comment: What does "not showing up" mean? In which template do you expect it will be output? Are there enough results for it to show up? What if you disable cck pager?

Comment: I found one more case when Views not showing pager. If you have Global: PHP field there is issue: [Pager disappears when Global: PHP used in Views 3.8](https://www.drupal.org/node/2276165)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out that i used multi-field selector which has its own set of **min-max** fields limits, which were by default set to display **all**. There was no conflicts between the CCK pager and the view pager nor with the pager id.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this problem can have a bunch of reasons depending on the site, therefore I'm adding my own answer that worked for me, even though the issue has already an accepted one.
In my case none of the google-findable answer worked, so I started debugging. The clue was viewing the paged view under another theme. Pager worked like a charm which led me to do regression tests with stuff like templates, theme.info region declarations and... functions in template.php. The latter was the answer - I had a `theme_item_list` override for some paths, and the switch was missing default case.

```
function MYTHEME_item_list($variables) {
  switch( drupal_get_path_alias($_GET['q']) ){
    case 'path/one':
    case 'path/two':
      // pasted raw function from theme.inc with wrapper tags removed: 
      // <div class="item-list"> and </div>
      // so to deliver required markup for jquery plugin
      $output = ....
      return $output;
    default: // was missing
      return theme_item_list($variables);
  }
}
```

So, to all ye who have problems with pager - the reason at your site can be completely different, but it might as well be buried in the theme assets you're using.